# Node.js OAuth2: Get Google+ activities

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-plus

From today I'm not able to retrieve my Google+ activities by placing a GET request to this url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/activities/public?key={API_KEY}
```

I'm getting a 401 error. So I tried to sign the request using the node.js oauth2 library, including a pre-generated user token, but I'm getting the same error. The js code for my test script is:

```
var OAuth2 = require('oauth').OAuth2,
    GOOGLEPLUS_APP_ID = {APP_ID},
    GOOGLEPLUS_APP_SECRET = {APP_SECRET},
    accessToken = {USER_TOKEN};

var _oauth2 = new OAuth2(GOOGLEPLUS_APP_ID, GOOGLEPLUS_APP_SECRET, '',
'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');

_oauth2.get('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/activities/public?key={API_KEY}',
accessToken, function (err, body, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error:');
        console.log(err);
    }
    else console.log(body);
});
```

I placed the same request to get the basic user info (url: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo) and works OK.

Can you please assist me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the access token already you should be able to use `{?|&}access_token=X` to get the result, example below.

```
var accessToken = 'XYZ';
require('http').get('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/activities/public?access_token=' + accessToken, function(result){
    //Use result here!
});
```

More information can be found within the [Google+ API (Common Parameters)](https://developers.google.com/+/api/#common-parameters) section

Comment: I tried to do that, but still throws the 401 error. It seems to be a signature problem, that's why I tried using the oauth library. Thank you.

Comment: Seemed to be a problem on the Google+ API. It's working back again without signing and adding the access token to the request.